# embed chatter tab in site.com communities

Tags: chatter, community, site.com

Is it possible to embed chatter tab in site.com communities ? I have seen an example posted [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/10/communities-plus-site-dot-com.html).How to achieve this.

Also Is it possible to include visualforce page tabs in site.com communities?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to replicate the entire Chatter tab functionality using Site.com at this time. Site.com includes two Chatter-related widgets, the News Feed and a Group Feed.

Comment: Thanks.Do you know how the chatter tab is included in that example

Comment: The chatter tab in that example is using the Salesforce.com tabs: You can find that functionality when you edit a community in the Tabs and Pages section.

Answer (score 0):

We cant embed chatter functionality using template of format -Kokua ,Koa &Napili .

Also Site.com don't support VF pages .

For using chatter functionality you need to go through Salesforce tab + VF template with minimum customization in branding.

However if we use any other template form Kokua ,Koa &Napili we can set naviagtion & topic , branding can be done but doesnt support chatter & vf pages .